# Mahout : Cannot convert into sequence file

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, mahout, sequencefile

I'm trying to convert some text files into mahout sequence files. So I do

```
mahout seqdirectory -i inputFolder -o outputFolder
```

But I always get this exception

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:403)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(CombineFileRecordReader.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileRecordReader.<init>(CombineFileRecordReader.java:126)
    at org.apache.mahout.text.MultipleTextFileInputFormat.createRecordReader(MultipleTextFileInputFormat.java:43)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:734)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:339)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:235)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(CombineFileRecordReader.java:155)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext, but class was expected
    at org.apache.mahout.text.WholeFileRecordReader.<init>(WholeFileRecordReader.java:52)
    ... 16 more
```

I'm running Mahout 0.8 on Hadoop 2.2.0

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous answers are incorrect. Mahout 0.8 had a MapReduce version of seqdirectory which was a new feature. A bug in the MR version was causing the exception you are seeing.

To execute seqdirectory with Mahout 0.8, please use the sequential version by specifying the -xm sequential option to your command line.

```
mahout seqdirectory -i inputFolder -o outputFolder -xm sequential
```

By default seqdirectory executes the MR version if none specified.

This issue has since been fixed in Mahout 0.9.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it finally worked but I also get an OutOfMemory exception.
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"

Comment: what r u trying to do?

Comment: I'm studying from Mahout Cookbook and I'm trying to do some excersises and examples. Now, I'm trying to convert into sequence files some text inputs from lastfm

Comment: It would help if u could post the stacktrace.

Comment: @SuneelMarthi: +1 for solving the error. Tried it for whole week.

Answer (score 1):

As I read somewhere that mahout 0.8 works with hadoop 1.2. I only downloaded mahout (it uses hadoop jar from lib/hadoop )

Comment: I think you're right, cause I tried it with hadoop 1.2.1 and it finaly worked.. Thanks for the response!

Comment: This has nothing to do with Hadoop version, look at my answer as to what the issue is. @webdev it would help if u could check the facts on mahout user lists before posting here.